# Posted Variable behaves differently on Razorpay payment script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables, post

I am trying to post customer and product details to Razorpay from a form. However, it does not trigger the same results as when I have the same variables in the receiving file. The code should be self explanatory;

The form

```
<form action="razorpay/index.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="cname" required><br>
Phone : <input type="phone" name="cphone" required><br>
Email : <input type="email" name="cemail" required><br>
Address : <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="caddress" required></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="gtotal" value="<?php echo $gtotal;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="vcomp" value="<?php echo $vcomp;?>">
<input type="hidden" name="proddescr" value="<?php echo $proddescr;?>">
<input type="submit" name="prodetsub">
```

The PHP file receiving the posted variables

```
<?php 

// If the below variables are not commented, the script works fine with the values

/*$_POST['prodetsub']="submit";
$_POST['gtotal']=8000;
$_POST['vcomp']="Chalo Bazaar";
$_POST['proddescr']="Product Description";
$_POST['cname']="Customer Name";
$_POST['cemail']="customer@email.com";
$_POST['caddress']="Customer Address, Line 1, Line 2, Line 3";
$_POST['cphone']="9999999999";
*/

///But if I try to receive the variables from the post as below, the variables are not passed to javascript and alerted.

if(isset($_POST['prodetsub'])){?>
<form action="charge.php" method="POST">
<?php 
$gtotal=trim($_POST['gtotal']);
$vcomp=trim($_POST['vcomp']);
$proddescr=trim($_POST['proddescr']);
$cname=trim($_POST['cname']);
$cemail=trim($_POST['cemail']);
$caddress=trim($_POST['caddress']);
$cphone=trim($_POST['cphone']);
echo $cname."<br>"; 
echo $cemail."<br>"; 
echo $cphone."<br>"; 
echo $caddress."<br>"; 
echo $gtotal."<br>"; 
echo $vcomp."<br>"; 
echo $proddescr."<br>"; 
?>
<button id="rzp-button1">Pay</button>
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
var x=<?php echo $gtotal;?>;
var mn="<?php echo $vcomp;?>";
var d="<?php echo $proddescr;?>";
var cn="<?php echo $cname;?>";
alert(cn);
    var cem="<?php echo $cemail;?>";
    alert(cem);
    var cadd="<?php echo $caddress;?>";
    alert(cadd);
    var cph="<?php echo $cphone;?>";
    alert(cph);

var options = {
"key": "rzp_test_WyK93y9mvps7SN",
"amount": x, // 2000 paise = INR 20
"name": mn,
"description": d,
"image": "../images/logo.png",
"handler": function (response){
    alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
},
"prefill": {
    "name": cn,
    "email": cem,
    "contact":cph
},
"notes": {
    "address": cadd
},
"theme": {
    "color": "#F37254"
}
};
var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);

document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
rzp1.open();
e.preventDefault();

}
</script>
  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_order_id" value="21">

</form>
<?php } else{echo "Nothing Submitted<br>";}?>
```

The variables echo perfectly in both cases. But they are not passed to the javascript in the case when it comes from the form. And so it does not trigger the alert in the javascript. However, when I activate the variables commented out at the top and have the values assigned in the same file, it works

I guess it is a small issue I am missing. But I have spent a lot of time trying to figure and have lost. Hope someone can see where I am going wrong.

EDIT :

I have json_encoded the variables now.

The Source Code shows values are properly output as follows

```
var x="30250";
var mn=""Chalo Bazaar"";
var d=""Unicorn Silver Colour. 4 Year old. In good Condition"";

    var cn=""Anit Gopinath"";
    alert(cn);
    var cem=""anitgopinath@gmail.com"";
    alert(cem);
    var cadd=""506\/C2, Panchganga,\r\nLok Upvan, Phase I, Pokhran II"";
    alert(cadd);
    var cph=""9833157945"";
    alert(cph);
```

The Chrome javascript console gives an error

"index.php:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I am wondering whether it is the slash in the address that is crashing the javascript

Comment: I am getting the variables echoed ...but they are not passed to javascript and it does not 'alert' the variables like it does when they are assigned in the same page. Because only if it does, then it will be passed to further payment processing as the further passing process is also done by javascript with their checkout.js

Comment: Right click your web page and choose "Source code". Watch the javascript code carefully : do you see the proper values in the variables?

Comment: Did that @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez still no luck

Comment: The variables have proper values in the source code

Comment: When JavaScript code has an error, it refuses to work, that's why you have to watch the javascript console (F12 key in Firefox).

Comment: I have just got it before I saw your comment,  the double quotes were the problem ! I removed them and am on ! Thanks a ton for all your efforts !

Comment: Why don't you post your comment to Answer ? So I can accept it ? :)

Comment: Ok, there it is my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the `alert` windows are not working, that usually happens when there is an error in the javascript code. We have to find out what the error is. Open the javascript console in your browser (F12 key in Mozilla Firefox).

Oh, the error are the **double double** quotes! So, in order to fix it, we can delete the `json_encode` calls, or we can remove the javascript double quotes.

Did it work? Great. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this:

```
var cem="<?php echo $cemail;?>";
```

You're directly dumping text from PHP into a Javascript context, and can trivially introduce JS syntax errors, killing the ENTIRE `<script>` block. Always use `json_encode()` when you're doing php->js output, e.g

```
var cem = <?php echo json_encode($cemail); ?>;
```

Why? Consider what happens if that var contains a `"`. Your code would generate this:

```
var cem = ""John Doe <jdoe@example.com"";
          ^^--- start/stop string
            ^^^^--- undefined variable
                 ^^^ another undefined variable
                     ^--- less than
                      ^^^^---even more undefined variables.
```

Comment: I have  json_encoded all the variables. Still no luck.

Comment: Your double quote point was right. However json_encode was not the exact answer. It was simple removing the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for a POST input name that has no value. Suggest checking on something else, like a hidden input.

```
// form has <input type="submit" name="prodetsub">
// which apparentl causes this to be false
if(isset($_POST['prodetsub'])){?>
```

Why not use something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="SUBMIT" value="1" />
// and check for form submit like 
if ((isset($_POST['SUBMIT'])) && ($_POST['SUBMIT'] ==1)){
```

Comment: the variables are POSTed and  are captured and echoed. I have no problem there. But they are not further passed on to the javascript as it should and does in the other scenario when the variables are assigned in the same page

Comment: right, it works when you assign a `value` to  $_POST['productsub']    but your form has no value for that input

Comment: I have assigned a value and still is the same.